# Creating a dialog for saving a csv file with C# and asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, httpresponse

Within my code I have an asp repeater and I wish to allow users to export the data from this to a csv file. Exporting to a csv works fine but when I wish to show a dialog box for users to choose where to save to nothing happens. I have went through several different solutions that apparently work but when I run them in my code nothing happens and I can not figure out why. This is my code at the moment:

```
protected void exportCSV_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string FilePath = Server.MapPath("~") + "\\test.csv";
        StringBuilder columnbind = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (Control item in rpt_bookings.Items)
        {
            Literal row1 = (Literal)item.FindControl("ltl_bookingemail");
            Literal row2 = (Literal)item.FindControl("ltl_bookingphone");
            Literal row3 = (Literal)item.FindControl("ltl_bookingcost");
            string fullRow = row1.Text.ToString() + "," + row2.Text.ToString() + "," + row3.Text.ToString();
            columnbind.Append(fullRow);
            columnbind.Append("\r\n");
        }
        //// Creates the file on server
        File.WriteAllText(FilePath, columnbind.ToString());
        string FileName = "test.csv";
        System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
        response.ClearContent();
        response.Clear();
        response.ContentType = "text/csv";
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName + ";");
        response.TransmitFile(FilePath);
        response.Flush();
        response.End();

        //// Deletes the file on server
        File.Delete(FilePath);

        //response.End();
        lblmsg.Text = "";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.Write(ex);
        Debug.Write(ex);
        lblmsg.Text = ex.Message;
        lblmsg.Style.Add("color", "#c73939");
    }
}
```

The csv is correctly created but nothing happens with the response. The code executes but nothing comes up on the screen at all. According to several other questions along the same lines this is the solution.

Comment: Try adding escaped quotes to the filename portion of the header;
`response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + FileName + "\";");`

Comment: @DanielPark That did not change anything

Answer (score 0):

Try the following changes:

```
response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=" + Filename + ";");
response.TransmitFile( FilePath );
response.End();
```

Don't delete the file in the next line but in the finally block instead:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    [..]
}
finally
{
    File.Delete(FilePath);
}
```